# Window azure and select cloud on the project types

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, azure

I Try to deploy existing project in window azure.I googled lot and find some  tutorials.I follow them.

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/119960/upgrade-your-aspnet-site-to-the-cloud/

http://netindonesia.net/blogs/wely/archive/2010/08/01/step-by-step-migrating-asp-net-application-to-windows-azure-part-1-preparing-the-application.aspx

I follow these links and download and install Windows `Azure SDK/Tolls`.But some thing I am missing here.I am with `VS2010`.Its my Add new web sites wizard.

[image: screen Shot]

but I am not  find as above link says.

`In the New Project dialog, select Visual C# > Cloud > Windows Azure Project`

Where is my  `Cloud > Windows Azure Project` option.May I missing some `sdk` to install or I am in totally wrong way? How to test that project locally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the "New Web Site" option.  You need to create a "New Project" and create a Web Application.  Once you have the Web Application Project created, you add another "New Project", then Cloud >> Windows Azure Cloud Service.

[image: In VS2012...]

[image: Cloud Project]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you installed, but the posts you're looking at are over two years old. If you visit [windowsazure.com](http://www.windowsazure.com), you'll see a link across the top called **Develop**. Click that, then go to **.NET** on the right. Then you'll see a few quick-links, one of them to **Install the SDK**. Choose that, and you'll see a choice for VS2010 or VS2012. Choose VS2010 and that should launch the right installer for you.

Once all that's done, fire up Visual Studio and you should have the cloud project.

Note: Within the .NET Develop page, there are also a few tutorials to get you started. Taking it to the next level, download the [Windows Azure Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396), which has labs for just about every Windows Azure service.

Comment: I got a error in above link `you must upgrade .NET4.5.....`.4.5 is necessary ?I have currently 4.0.